# EE Session and cURL

Tags: sessions, curl

Is it possible to retain the EE session when accessing a url in the same domain via cURL?

This is because the page accessed in the cURL call is dependent on EE's session variables.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about php developing not really related to EE. cURL can do everything what regular person can do. Just need to use cURL with --cookie

Comment: This is still EE related since I think EE's sessions are different from Native PHP

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware you will need to do something special, Max alluded to being able to set a cookie. Without doing so your cURL request is seen as a totally separate session since it's initiated by your server, not by your browser.

Comment: It seems to me that you can access `$_COOKIE['exp_sessionid']` to get the current sessionid. However, I still don't know how to make use of this information to retain EE session when using cURL.

Answer (score 1):

This my be useful to you, it describes how to use cURL with session cookies

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php